# simple explanation of gaussian mixture model

Tags: probability, statistics

I need some help understanding Gaussian mixture models. In particular, I am trying to find the relationship between GMMs and K means. What is the basic algorithm for GMM? I am not sure where the "clustering" comes in. Can someone give me a basic example as to how this actually works?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a training set $\{ x_1, \dots, x_k \}$. Then you are assuming that each of the $x_i$ was drawn from some Gaussian Distribution $N(\mu_j, \Sigma_j)$ depending on some latent variable $z_i$.